# Add Navigation Drawer with Tabs in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-tablayout

Acualy i created a navigation Drawer activity and this activiy works perfectly but i want to add the first item of Navigaion Drawer with tab layout and the remaining item with the fragments(which i already done) so please hep me how can i do this:

NavigationDrawer Activity:

```
public class NotificationDrawer extends AppCompatActivity {

private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private View navHeader;
private ImageView imgNavHeaderBg, imgProfile;
private TextView txtName, txtWebsite;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private static final String urlProfileImg = "http://www.google/images.com;
public static int navItemIndex = 0;

// tags used to attach the fragments
private static final String TAG_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_VEHICLE = "vehicle";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS= "address";
public static String CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;

// toolbar titles respected to selected nav menu item
private String[] activityTitles;

// flag to load home fragment when user presses back key
private boolean shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress = true;
private Handler mHandler;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_navigation);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   // toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_sort_white_24dp);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 /*   getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled( true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_sort_white_24dp);*/
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_sort_white_24dp);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
           // Navigation view header
    navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txtName = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtWebsite = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.website);
    imgNavHeaderBg = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_header_bg);
    imgProfile = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_profile);

    // load toolbar titles from string resources
    activityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);

    // load nav menu header data
 //  loadNavHeader();
    txtName.setText("Techiee");
    txtWebsite.setText("www.techiee.com");
    // initializing navigation menu
    setUpNavigationView();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        navItemIndex = 0;
        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
        loadHomeFragment();
    }
}

private void loadHomeFragment() {
    // selecting appropriate nav menu item
    selectNavMenu();

    // set toolbar title
    setToolbarTitle();
  if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();

        // show or hide the fab button
        //toggleFab();
        return;
    }

    Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                    android.R.anim.fade_out);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    };

    // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
    if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
        mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
    }

    // show or hide the fab button
    //toggleFab();

    //Closing drawer on item click
    drawer.closeDrawers();

    // refresh toolbar menu
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
    switch (navItemIndex) {
        case 0:
            // home
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            return homeFragment;
        case 1:
            // registered_vehicle
            Registered_Vehicle registeredVehicle = new Registered_Vehicle();
            return registeredVehicle;
        case 2:
            // registeredAddress fragment
            RegisteredAddress registeredAddress = new RegisteredAddress();
            return registeredAddress;

        default:
            return new HomeFragment();
    }
}

private void setToolbarTitle() {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(activityTitles[navItemIndex]);
}

private void selectNavMenu() {
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
}

private void setUpNavigationView() {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        //    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                    break;
                case R.id.registered_vehi:
                    navItemIndex = 1;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_VEHICLE;
                    break;
                case R.id.registered_address:
                    navItemIndex = 2;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_ADDRESS;
                    break;
                    drawer.closeDrawers();

                    navItemIndex = 0;
            }

            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                menuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
            }
            menuItem.setChecked(true);

            loadHomeFragment();

            return true;
        }
    });


    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };


    //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
    drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon wont show up
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_sort_white_24dp);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });
}
```

drawer_navigation.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/buttonbackground"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
```

>

Comment: what is the problem with your implementation?

Comment: i don't know how to add the tabLayout with NavigationDrawer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the `Tablayout` with `NavigationDrawer` :

1.create a new File “`TabFragment.java`” to inflate & code `TabLayout` and `viewPager` elements.

2.For `viewPager` to display content it requires a Adapter . use a `FragmentPagerAdapter`  which is used to inflate tab specific fragments.

3.The `FragmentPagerAdapter` overrides three main methods  :

a) `getCount`() : It returns the total number of tabs to be bind with the view pager.

b) `getItem`(int position) : It returns the tab-specific fragment wrt to its position.

c) `getPageTitle`(int position)` : It returns name of the title according to the position

4.At the end , attach your `ViewPager` with the `TabLayout` with the `setupWithViewPager(viewPager)` method of the `TabLayout` .

Here is a detail implementation: https://androidbelieve.com/navigation-drawer-with-swipe-tabs-using-design-support-library/

Hope it helps.

As u are using `toolbar` you can use:

```
    @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
    if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
    else menuItem.setChecked(true);

    //Closing drawer on item click
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

    //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.first:
            toolbar.setTitle("First Item");
            return true;

    case R.id.second:
            toolbar.setTitle("Second Item");
            return true;
     }
}
```

to set title..during click on fragments

Comment: can u please tell me how can i set the title during onClick fragments

Comment: title to where?

Comment: actualy i tried befor using getSupportActionBar().setTitle("HOME");
but i don't why it cause a app crash.....
toolbar.setTitle works perfectly fine