# Android navigation drawer with tab layout in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am new to android and I am going to design this kind of layout that is complex to me. Here's the code of `main_activity.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/home_view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout_home"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Basically I have in my main activity a Navigation drawer and 3 tabs. Here's a picture:

[image]

Everything works as I want and I'm happy.

---

When I click on a navigation drawer item I start a new intent to open a new activity and it's good but the drawer disappears of course (becase the new activity does NOT have the drawer). I want to keep the drawer in the screen always.

To keep the drawer on my screen I thought that I could have placed the TabLayout of the above XML as a fragment; in this way the drawer would still be there. But how can I do this? How can I place the TabLayout in a fragment so that I can replace this fragment with TabLayout or other fragments?

I think that I could put a FrameLayout instead of TabLayout but I do not know if it's good idea and how would it work. Any help?

There are similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890065/add-navigation-drawer-with-tabs-in-fragment) but they haven't helped me because I'm still stuck here

---

**More.** If you click on results, the ThisSeason activity is launched and it has some fragments inside (inclusing ResultsFragments). That works, but there is no navigation drawe anymore and I have to press the back button!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a general idea for implementing this.

1. Make a base activity for your application.
2. Then make fragment for each activity including the screen which has tabs. So, if you have 5 items in nav view then total of 6 fragments will be created.
3. Add the nav view and related functions in the main activity xml and java file. This will basically add navigation view to the base activity and since you're using fragments, all the pages(fragments) will have the navigation view.

Additional Note: You can make multiple subclasses to handle specific functions, like one for handling actionMode, navigation view and updating the title in the toolbar. You get the point.

Also, all the features which are common to all the fragments should be added in the base activity only instead of repeating the same code everywhere.